# How to add TypeScript types to destructured parameters using spread syntax?

Tags: typescript, destructuring, spread-syntax

Ignore the fact that this is bad `add` function. It's a question about using array destructuring with spread syntax in TypeScript.

This is what I'm trying

```
const add = ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return 0
  else
    return x + add(xs)
}

console.log(add([1,2,3])) //=> 6
```

But I have no idea how to add TypeScript types to this. My best guess is to do something like this (most direct translation)

```
const add = (xs: number[]): number => {
  if (xs[0] === undefined)
    return 0;
  else
    return xs[0] + add(xs.slice(1));
};

console.log(add([1,2,3])); // => 6
```

Both functions work, but in TypeScript I lose the ability to destructure the array parameter and the function body is junked up with a bunch of ugly stuff like `xs[0]` and `xs.slice(1)` – even if I abstract these into their own functions, that's besides the point.

Is it possible in add types to destructured spread parameters in TypeScript?

---

**What I've tried so far**

Something like this works for fixed arrays

```
// compiles
const add = ([x,y,z]: [number, number, number]): number => ...
```

But of course I need variable length array input. I tried this, but it doesn't compile

```
// does not compile
const add = ([x, ...xs]: [number, number[]]): number => ...
```

Comment: Theoretically what you're saying should work using the spread operator... https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/spread-operator.html. Oh, you want to add types... I just read the rest of this

Comment: Yeah, I found that too – I don't know enough about TypeScript, but I thought that was a really strange page to have in that book. I mean, who cares about these features in TypeScript if you can't use them with *types* ...

Comment: I don't think this is supported with spread. If the array if of fixed length you can do: `[x, y, z]: [number, number, number]` but that's it :(

Comment: Yeah, I tried something similar. I'll update my question to help people that might waste time in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad, the answer is as simple as:

```
const add = ([x, ...xs]: number[]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return 0
  else
    return x + add(xs)
}

console.log(add([1, 2, 3])); //=> 6
add(["", 4]); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20add%20%3D%20(%5Bx%2C%20...xs%5D%3A%20number%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(x%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%20%2B%20add(xs)%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(add(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D))%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%206%0Aadd(%5B%22%22%2C%204%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

---

#### Original answer:

You can do this:

```
const add: (nums: number[]) => number = ([x, ...xs]) => {
    if (x === undefined)
        return 0
    else
        return x + add(xs)
}
```

You can also use a type alias:

```
type AddFunction = (nums: number[]) => number;

const add: AddFunction = ([x, ...xs]) => {
    ...
}
```

Comment: guh... that is *so* fricken awkward – especially because we must provide a name for the type (in this case `nums`). it's so counter-intuitive because `nums` is an identifier that's not actually available in the scope of `add`. It bothers me to no end that [TypeScript forces you to specify identifiers that aren't usable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42322251/633183). Anyway, thanks for providing a solution for this. -1 for TypeScript, +1 for you.

Comment: Well, I did not completely understand you. Check my revised answer.

Comment: OK, redemption number 1! Thanks heaps. I'd be thrilled to have you look at that other question to let me know if there's a redemption number 2 ^_^