# Do I have to specify parameter names for higher-order function types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, higher-order-functions

Trying to get my feet wet using TypeScript and I keep running into [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42321953/633183). An [old function resurfaced today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34256998/633183) and just as an exercise, I was curious if I could convert it to TypeScript. So far it's been a complete pain in the neck.

```
declare type Ord = number | string;

// type signature for f sucks really bad
// (f: Ord => Ord => boolean) would be really nice, if possible
// but instead I have to give names (_) for the parameters? dumb
const arrayCompare = (f: (_: Ord) => (_: Ord) => boolean) => ([x,...xs]: Ord[]) => ([y,...ys]: Ord[]): boolean => {
  if (x === undefined && y === undefined)
    return true;
  else if (! f (x) (y))
    return false;
  else
    return arrayCompare (f) (xs) (ys);
}

// here the names of the parameters are actually used
const eq = (x: Ord) => (y: Ord) : boolean => x === y;

// well at least it works, I guess ...
console.log(arrayCompare (eq) ([1,2,3]) ([1,2,3]));             // true
console.log(arrayCompare (eq) (['a','b','c']) (['a','b','c'])); // true
```

So the question is specifically about (see **bold**)

```
const arrayCompare = (f: (_: Ord) => (_: Ord) => boolean) => ...
```

`f` is expecting a higher-order function of the type

```
Ord => Ord => boolean
```

But if I use this type signature

```
// danger !! unnamed parameters
(f: (Ord) => (Ord) => boolean)
```

TypeScript will assume `Ord` as the *name* of the parameter and the implied type is `any`

```
// what TypeScript thinks it means
(f: (Ord: any) => (Ord: any) => boolean)
```

Of course this is not what I want, but that's what I get anyway. In order to get what I actually want, I have to specify the names of the parameters for the higher-order function

```
// now it's correct
(f: (_: Ord) => (_: Ord) => boolean)
```

But c'mon that makes no sense. I only have access to `f` in this context, not to the parameters that `f` will bind when I eventually call it...

**Question**

Why do I have to provide *names* for higher-order function parameters in TypeScript?

It makes no sense and makes the function signatures long, ugly, harder to write, and harder to read.

---

**UPDATE**

> *"as far as names for parameters, consider a function that takes a callback of -> (number -> number -> number) ->, so based solely on the types your options are: add, subtract, multiply, divide, power, compare of which only one makes sense, now if a callback parameter had a name add: (number -> number -> number) the choice would be obvious"* – [Aleksey Bykov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322251/do-i-have-to-specify-parameter-names-for-higher-order-function-types-in-typescri/42322780?noredirect=1#comment71798752_42322304)

I'm happy to be given an opportunity to reply to this. I can name heaps more functions with `(number -> number -> number)` signature.

- `first`, `second`, `mod`, `min`, `max`
- bitwise functions `&`, `|`, `xor`, `<<`, and `>>`
- `(x, y) => sqrt(sq(x) + sq(y))`
- `(x, y) => x + x + y + y + superglobalwhocares`
- and *any* other function you can dream up

To clear things up, I'm not suggesting the function parameter itself should not be given a name. I'm suggesting that function parameter's *parameters* should not be given names ...

```
// this
func = (f: (number => number => number)) => ...

// not this
func = (f: (foo: number) => (bar: number) => number)) => ...
```

Why? well because `f` has no knowledge of the parameters of the function that I will be providing.

```
// for the record, i would never name parameters like this
// but for those that like to be descriptive, there's nothing wrong with these
const add = (addend: number) => (augend: number) => number ...
const sub = (minuend: number) => (subtrahend: number) => number ...
const divide = (dividend: number) => (divisor: number) => number ...
const mult = (multiplicand: number) => (multiplier: number) => number ...

// I could use any of these with my func
func (add ...)
func (sub ...)
func (divide ...)
func (mult ...)
```

I couldn't provide names for `f`'s parameters in `func` if I tried ! Because who knows which function I will use? All of them are appropriate.

If I try to put names on them, I pigeonholed the user's imagination of what the function is capable of ...

```
// maybe the user thinks only a division function can be specified (?)
func = (f: (dividend: number) => (divisor: number) => number) => ...
```

`dividend` and `divisor` are not a good fit here because any of the functions listed above would fit. At **best** I could do this

```
// provide generic name for f's parameters
func = (f: (x: number) => (y: number) => number) => ...
```

But then what's the point? It's not like `x` and `y` become bound identifiers. And `x` and `y` offer no added description – which I suppose brings me to *my* point: they're not *meant* to have a name or description. `f` has *zero* knowledge of the way we might use it, but it doesn't matter; as long as it has a `(number => number => number)` interface, that's *all* we care about. And that's the *most* useful information we can provide to the user of our `func` regarding the `f` parameter.

> *"It would be quite confusing for function like:*
>
> ```
> foo(cb: (number, number) => (number, string) => boolean)
> ```
>
> *What does it do?"* - [unional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42322317/633183)

Same exact reasoning applies here. Besides the fact that `(cb: (number, number) => (number, string) => boolean))` is a poorly-designed function (how many useful mixed-type quaternary (4-arity) functions can you name?), it *doesn't* matter. `f` can't pretend to know any descriptors about the countless functions I could come up with that use such a signature.

So my question is, why the heck do I have to specify **overtly** meaningless names for function parameter *parameters* ?

---

**Exercise**

Can you replace `_` with meaningful names?

```
const apply2 = (f: (_: number) => (_: number) => number) => (x: number) => (y: number): number => {
    return f (x) (y)
};

const sqrt = (x: number): number => Math.sqrt(x);
const sq = (x: number): number => x * x;
const add = (addend: number) => (augend: number): number => addend + augend;
const pythag = (side1: number) => (side2: number): number => sqrt(add(sq(side1)) (sq(side2)));

console.log(apply2 (add) (3) (4));    // 7
console.log(apply2 (pythag) (3) (4)); // => 5
```

If not, can you make a compelling argument why such names *must* be present in your TypeScript signature?

Comment: That's already 2 significant problems for a single generic JavaScript function – if there's no reasonable remedy for this, I honestly don't see how TypeScript is useful for people.

Comment: there hasn't been a problem for declaring a sorting function for an array in TS ever: `sort<T>(values: T[], compare:  (one :T, another: T) => number): T[]`

Comment: We define "problem" differently — `one` and `another` are unused (*useless*) identifiers. They're not available for use by the function and only serve to make the function signature longer and more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: names tell stories and deliver the original intent of their author, is this usless?

Comment: Lol this thread is getting ridiculous — I don't want to tell a story, I want to define a function signature with as little information as is needed to accurately define the *type* of the function. First order functions can name their parameters so higher order functions don't have to. Anyway, there's obviously a difference of principles here. It's apparent that TypeScript offers no such brief, succinct declarations.

Comment: You can not take an isolated issue and declare a language useless. Languages have strengths and weaknesses and depending on the problem domain they fit better or worse. The static type system of TS is a huge improvement to JS.

Comment: @Sefe I respectfully disagree. I was playing with flow this evening and added types to my functions and had type safety within minutes. TypeScript's inability to handle these basic cases makes it a very misguided derivative of JavaScript, imo. Maybe we didn't need a new language after all? Maybe we just needed an expressive type checker. I'll post the results tomorrow for anyone that's interested.

Comment: Maybe you write that expressive type checker. If you make something better than what we have, I promise I'd be the first one to use it.

Comment: consider a callback ` -> (string -> string -> string -> string) ->` now tell me which string is first name, last name and email, in stupid TS it's not a question: `fn: (email: string, last: string, first: string) => string`, i hope the point is clear

Comment: @AlekseyBykov you're too narrowed on this concept you have of "callbacks" – In my updated question, I just explained a scenario where the "callback" (`f`) could not possibly provide names for the arguments (other than generic names `x` and `y`). This is because `func` can be called with *any* `(number -> number -> number)` function where the names of those parameters could vary widely.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov If you're still missing my point, I've added an **Exercise** section to my question.

Comment: @Sefe I was referring to [flowtype](https://flowtype.org/). However, it's not without its problems too. It was working fine with concrete types, but as soon as I wanted to introduce polymorphism with the curried function, it [breaks down](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2105). Oh well.

Comment: there are times when names are useless, there are times when names are helpful, why are you trying to split the world into black and white? get over it, enjoy variety of options, use it to make something of value

as to original question why would anyone use names, because they had to make a difficult choice (there is no solution in between having names and prohibiting them), and they made it.. now what?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov I don't know why you and Sefe are having such difficulty understanding the problem I'm actually talking about. But there's no sense in beating a dead horse – it's obvious that TypeScript isn't right for me, but I'm having some trouble understanding who it's for if it needs to be so verbose to type simple things. Thanks for chatting. I'm sorry if you feel like you've wasted your time.

Comment: I went back and forth on this for a while but I'm closing this question in favor of the newer one above, since the... uh... *spirited* discussion here is mostly opinion.  The question "why does TS require parameter names in the types of function signatures" has a canonical-ish answer (even if it is a disappointing one) which is given by the GitHub issues linked in the answer to the other question.  Hope this doesn't step on too many toes; cheers to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to write currying definitions, at least in a way that is readable.
I would do is to extract the signatures outside of the function declaration as much as possible, something like this:

```
type Ord = string | number;
type ThirdFunction = (objs: Ord[]) => boolean;
type SecondFunction = (objs: Ord[]) => ThirdFunction;
type FirstFunction = (fn: (o: Ord) => (o: Ord) => boolean) => SecondFunction;

const arrayCompare: FirstFunction = f => ([x,...xs]) => ([y,...ys]) => {
    ...
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Ord%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0Atype%20ThirdFunction%20%3D%20(objs%3A%20Ord%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0Atype%20SecondFunction%20%3D%20(objs%3A%20Ord%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20ThirdFunction%3B%0Atype%20FirstFunction%20%3D%20(fn%3A%20(o%3A%20Ord)%20%3D%3E%20(o%3A%20Ord)%20%3D%3E%20boolean)%20%3D%3E%20SecondFunction%3B%0A%0Aconst%20arrayCompare%3A%20FirstFunction%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20(%5Bx%2C...xs%5D)%20%3D%3E%20(%5By%2C...ys%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(x%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%26%26%20y%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%0A%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0A%20%20else%20if%20(!%20f%20(x)%20(y))%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arrayCompare%20(f)%20(xs)%20(ys)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20here%20the%20names%20of%20the%20parameters%20are%20actually%20used%0Aconst%20eq%20%3D%20(x%3A%20Ord)%20%3D%3E%20(y%3A%20Ord)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%3D%3D%3D%20y%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20well%20at%20least%20it%20works%2C%20I%20guess%20...%0Aconsole.log(arrayCompare%20(eq)%20(%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D)%20(%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D))%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20true%0Aconsole.log(arrayCompare%20(eq)%20(%5B'a'%2C'b'%2C'c'%5D)%20(%5B'a'%2C'b'%2C'c'%5D))%3B%20%2F%2F%20true))

I also removed the `declare` you had before the `Ord` type alias, there's no need for it.  And you can find better names for the types.
Another thing is that you don't need to specify the `boolean` here:

```
const eq = (x: Ord) => (y: Ord) : boolean => x === y;
```

Can be:

```
const eq = (x: Ord) => (y: Ord) => x === y;
```

---

Or you could express the function using a single `type` declaration. Readability is fairly decent, all things considered.

```
type Ord = number | string;

type arrayCompareFunc = (f: (x: Ord) => (y: Ord) => boolean)
                      => (xs: Ord[])
                      => (ys: Ord[])
                      => boolean;

const arrayCompare: arrayCompareFunc = f => ([x,...xs) => ([y,...ys) => {
   ...
};
```

Comment: I suppose `boolean` can be implied because of the `return _ === _`?

Comment: yeah, the compiler infers that on its own.

Comment: Instead of posting a separate answer, I made an edit that demonstrates the consolidation the three function data types into one. I hope you'll agree it maintains the original spirit of your answer. Thanks for your help. I think this is as close as we're gonna get.

Comment: Sure thing. If you think that's clearer.  Currying isn't pretty.

Answer (score 0):

1. this is a very impractical way of using functions in JS
2. TS sucks at generics on function references, so a lot of intuition from Haskell just doesnt work here

back to your question, you have to provide names because TS syntax is such that requires you to do so, rational part is that a name of a parameter conveys additional meaning when the type alone fails to do so

Comment: *"this is a very impractical way of using functions in JS"* – Maybe TypeScript's type system is inflexible or inexpressive, but that doesn't affect the practicality or usefulness of generic/higher-order functions. *Naming* parameters where they don't need to be named is outright silly. In my example here, you can't even use the identifiers you're forced to provide in the scope of `arrayCompare` – the only context in which the identifier would matter is in the higher-order function itself; in this case `eq`.

Comment: i didnt mean higher functions when i said impractical, what i meant is currying which has first class support in haskell but way too cumbersome and expensive in JS (note i haven't said a word about TS so far)

Comment: Currying is not cumbersome in JavaScript tho... :(

Comment: as far as names for parameters, consider a function that takes a callback of `-> (number -> number -> number) ->`, so based solely on the types your options are: `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide`, `power`, `compare` of which only one makes sense, now if a callback parameter had a name `add: (number -> number -> number)` the choice would be obvious

Comment: I'm please to be given the opportunity to reply. I've updated my question to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `(f: (Ord) => (Ord) => boolean)`, all TypeScript sees is that your are specifying function with one argument named `Ord`. You have not specify the type.

EDIT: I can see that it is a limitation in the current TypeScript. A request is filed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14173

In order to support this syntax, the compiler (and the language service) would need to introduce names themselves.

Consider when the code is being used:
[image]

It provides the same syntax as how a function should be defined in TypeScript. i.e. `(name: Type) => ...`. If name is not introduced, it would be very confusing to the user.

On the other hand, if the arguments carry any specific meaning, it worthwhile IMO to provide the argument name, so that user know what to do.

It would be quite confusing for function like:

`foo(cb: (number, number) => (number, string) => boolean)`

What does it do?

Comment: Yes, but that is the syntax of TypeScript. It is non intrusive. Without the types, TypeScript is just JavaScript.  The variable name in JavaScript does not and should be be used to suggest type. :)

Comment: I understand you're trying to help, but this doesn't answer my question at all. Telling me *"TypeScript is just Javascript"* is something I'm already aware of :(

Comment: I can see your point. As `f: ...` meaning `(Ord) => ...` is pure type decoration. Maybe you can suggest a feature request at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript

Comment: thanks for the reply – I've addressed your updated answer with an update to my question. I'll be filing a feature request thanks to your recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

> So my question is, why the heck do I have to specify **overtly** meaningless names for function parameter parameters ?

I don't think they are meaningless. I can think of *at least* three good reasons why naming the parameters makes sense:

**Consistency**

This is how you define property types in TypeScript:

```
class Person {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public age: number;
}
```

This is how you specify variable types:

```
let person: Person;
```

Parameter types:

```
function meet(who: Person) {
}
```

Function and method return types:

```
function isUnderage(person: Person): boolean {
    return person.age < 18;
}
```

This is how function type parameters would look without parameter names:

```
let myFunc: (string, string, number) => boolean;
```

...or...

```
function myFuncWithCallback(callback: (string, string, number) => boolean): void {}
```

...or...

```
type CallbackType = (string, string, number) => boolean;
let myFunc: CallbackType;
function myFuncWithCallback(callback: CallbackType): void {}
```

This doesn't quite fit with the other declarations above.

Throughout TypeScript, whenever you use types to signify static typing of a target you go with `target: type`. That's easy to remember. If you start making rules like: Use the syntax `target: type` in all cases *except* when defining parameters of function types, this makes your language less consistent and thus more difficult to learn and to use. It might technically not be necessary, but consistency is a value by itself. JavaScript is full of quirks and TypeScript is inheriting a lot of them. Better not introduce any additional inconsistencies.
So this is not an uncommon pattern and that is for good reasons.

**`this` parameters**

Without specifying parameter names in function types, specifying [`this` parameters in callback types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters-in-callbacks) would become even more messy and inconsistent. Consider this example from the linked page:

```
interface UIElement {
    addClickListener(onclick: (this: void, e: Event) => void): void;
}
```

You would want it like this:

```
interface UIElement {
    addClickListener(onclick: (this: void, Event) => void): void;
}
```

So then the rule would be "Use the syntax `target: type` everywhere, *except* function types, where it is just the type in the parameters, *unless* there is a `this` parameter, then it actually is that syntax, but only in the `this` parameter." I don't blame the TypeScript designers to rather go with the rule "Use the syntax `target: type` everywhere."

**Development aids**

This is what I get when I hover over a function in TypeScript:

[image: JQuery.each]

How would you like it to read `func: (number, Element) => any` instead of the descriptive parameter names it has? The type information is pretty useless by itself. And any code automatically generated from this definition would have to give the parameters meaningless names like `param1` and `param2`. That's obviously not optimal.

TypeScript is not the only language naming the paramters of function types:

C# delegates are defined like this:

```
delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Delphi function variables:

```
type TFunc = function(x: Integer, y: Integer): Integer;
```

Comment: You're not reading my question correctly. Your entire reply is a counter argument for something I never said. Normal function parameters need names anyway; those are the identifiers that get bound when the function is applied. I'm specifically talking about a function parameter's *parameters* requiring a name as being pointless. Read the **exercise** posted at the bottom of my question closely — I'm only referring to the `_`-named parameters.

Comment: I dont see how I'm referring to anything different than you do. This is turning into a waste of my time.

Comment: I'm not saying Object properties shouldn't have names. I'm not saying function parameters shouldn't have names. I'm saying function parameter *parameters* shouldn't have names. Looking at the exercise, do you see the `f`, `x`, and, `y`? Your post reads as tho I'm saying *no* parameters should have names, but that's definitely *not* what I'm saying. Those are normal function parameters and they absolutely need a name. I'm talking specifically about `f`s parameters – the `_` names – *those* don't make any sense.

Comment: If you can't tell the semantic difference between `f` and `f`'s parameters (the two `_` identifiers), then it's impossible for me to describe the problem to you. There *is* a difference – a significant one – and it's worth it for you to learn what distinguishes one from the other.

Comment: I _am_ referring to function parameters.

Comment: Yeah well I'm *not* ! I'm referring to function parameter *parameters*. Function parameters need a name, obviously. Function parameter *parameters* do not. – I can't spell this out for you any clearer: `f` is a function parameter – yes, we agree that `f` needs a name. However, `f`'s parameters (`_: number` and `_: number`) do *not* need names.

Comment: Anyway, you're refusing to do the exercise. You have not replaced `_` with a meaningful name. What names would you suggest belong there?

Comment: @Mulan "_function parameter parameters_"  seems a little misleading, "_type annotation of function (as a parameter of higher-order function)_" maybe better, so long :D