# Why do Typescript function type signatures include parameter names

Tags: typescript

New to typescript, so maybe I'm missing something here...

I was trying to write a simple filter function on a container I'd made

```
class Container<T> {
    filter(predicate: (T) => boolean): Container<T> {
        for(const element of this.contents) {
            if(predicate(element))
```

and tslint gave me an error about starting variables with capital letters (which is a rule I have on purpose).  I wasn't sure what it meant at first, but apparently it's taking the T in (T) => boolean to be the name of the parameter, and not the type.  After googling around for some typescript callback examples, I saw everyone typing a function signature as

```
(paramName: ParamType) => ReturnType.
```

But it seems like the paramName here is pointless.  I'm not declaring the function here, I'm just giving its signature.  Why is this valid Typescript?

Comment: A similar question has been handled in this [q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322251/do-i-have-to-specify-parameter-names-for-higher-order-function-types-in-typescri/42333585#42333585).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official reason appears to be to "help with readability"

> A function’s type has the same two parts: the type of the arguments and the return type. When writing out the whole function type, both parts are required. **We write out the parameter types just like a parameter list, giving each parameter a name and a type. This name is just to help with readability.** ...
>
> -- [TypeScript Handbook - Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

You are correct that the names are not used.