# Explicit typing with spread operator

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0, strong-typing

For the below syntax,

```
let [first, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(typeof first); // number
console.log(typeof rest);  // object
```

**Edit:**

`[a,b]:number[]` or `[a, ...b]:number[]` scenario is different. you want `first` to be like `[number,..]` type but not part of `number[]` type

How to explicitly type this syntax? Because `let [first, ...rest]:[number, object] = [1, 2, 3, 4];` does not work

Comment: `typeof rest` is `"object"` because that's what JavaScript says for an array at runtime, nothing to do TypeScript's type system. The TS type of `rest` should already be `number[]` in your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add TypeScript types to destructured parameters using spread syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321953/how-to-add-typescript-types-to-destructured-parameters-using-spread-syntax)

Comment: @Andreas `[a,b]:number[]` or `[a, ...b]:number[]` scenario is different. you want `first` to be  `[number,..]` type but not part of `number[]` type

Comment: And the problem is? Just check the _playground_ link in the accepted answer. First element = string -> error; first element = number -> no error

Comment: @Andreas  I think you are right!!!

Comment: Logging `typeof` at runtime does **not** tell you what the TypeScript compiler has inferred at compile time. As you'd expect, the types of `first` and `rest` are inferred as `number` and `number[]`, respectively.