# Explicit typing of default parameters

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321953/how-to-add-typescript-types-to-destructured-parameters-using-spread-syntax)

For the below code,

```
type C = { a: string, b: number }

function f({ a, b } = {a:"", b:0}): void {
    // ...
}
```

What is the syntax to explicitly type the default parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare the type before the assignment.

```
type C = { a: string, b: number }

function f({ a, b }: C = {a:"", b:0}): void {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It compiles now.